# djongo(django + mongo) trouble with inspectdb, unable to inspectdb and import model

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-migrations, djongo

I am newbie to python and django, 
Using Django version: 4.1.10 and python version : 3.11.4 
I have existing mongodb database so I am trying complete migration and import models in djongo (django + mongo) with inspectdb.
But I run this command 
`python manage.py inspectdb` 
 I keep getting following err,

```
    PS C:\Users\del\Downloads\splc\jango\splc1> python manage.py inspectdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\del\Downloads\splc\jango\splc1\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\del\Downloads\splc\jango\splc1\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\del\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 936, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1074, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1004, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
SyntaxError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

also when I run
`python manage.py inspectdb items > splc1app/models.py` 
I keep geeting an error which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/issues/299) as well
What am I missing here, any help is really appriciated.

Comment: There is something wrong in your INSTALLED APP, please check.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'splc1app.apps.Splc1AppConfig',
]

these are things from installed app,I guess these are required , Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: I think this 'splc1app.apps.Splc1AppConfig' has an issue, remove it and try again.